# file RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem adding root link files to a laravel project

This is the file Route:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::prefix("dashboard")->group(function(){

     Route::get('/test', function () {
         return '<h1>test</h1>';
     })->name('test');

});
```

These are the functions in the RouteServiceProvider file:

```
     public function boot()
     {
         $this->configureRateLimiting();

         $this->routes(function () {
             Route::middleware('api')
                 ->prefix('api')
                 ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

             Route::middleware('web')
                 ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

             Route::middleware('web')
             ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));
   
         });
    
     }
```

But I still get the error (404 page not found):
404
NOT FOUND

Please help generate the code, thanks

You guys have really great information

Comment: What is the route you're trying to access. that's giving the 404?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/dashboard/test

Comment: Try to launch command `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Also, launch command `php artisan route:list ` and check if you have this route

Comment: what is the name of your `Route` file? `web.php`?

Comment: dashboard.php file is within the route folder

Comment: I tried clear route commend and it didn't work, Is there a solution for that.